# Making slds-list_horizontal work well in a lighting-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds, lightning-datatable

I'd like to use [slds-list_horizontal slds-has-dividers_left slds-has-block-links_space](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/horizontal-list/#Left-with-Link-Space) styling for zero or more dates all placed in a `lightning-datatable` cell but get these results...

In "Clip text" mode for the column:

[image: "Clip text" example]

In "Wrap text" mode for the column:

[image: "Wrap text" example]

In "Wrap text" mode for the column with the column dragged narrower:

[image: "Wrap text" example with column dragged narrower]

Can anyone offer advice that results in the ellipsis indication (the three dots) for the first case and handles the second and third cases better e.g. wraps on the individual items?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but you could try, at least for the first approach (maybe is valid for the second as well), something like

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Returned', fieldName: 'Returned__c', 
      cellAttributes: 
        { class: 'slds-truncate'}
    }, // other column data
];
```

Other option could be loading a static resource in your LWC where you define the
CSS scoping table cells like `<td>` with something like:

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel; I'll give these ago. Might well just resort to a vertical list though...

Comment: The `slds-truncate` didn't help on the `li` or the `ul`. Will go with the plain vertical list.

Comment: If you want to share your LWC with the datatable version (maybe in a playground) I can try a few things on my own and let you know if I manage to make it look better. Otherwise vertical list sounds like another valid approach to me as well.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel but it is fairly convoluted requiring a custom data table and a couple of custom components. So it is vertical for me. Thanks for your answer.